# SSl for Tomcat 6 doesn't work when run from Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, ssl, netbeans, tomcat6

When I run Tomcat 6 from the cmd line, the SSL works fine.  When I run it from within Netbeans, it fails to start with the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No Certificate file specified or invalid file format
```

The SSL Configuration is the default out-the-box one:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           />
```

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by changing the SSL configuration to:

```
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               />
```

i.e. explicitly specifying the protocol.  It turns out this is implied in the Tomcat docs:

> "The example above will throw an error if you have the APR and the
>   Tomcat Native libraries in your path, as Tomcat will try to use the
>   APR connector. The APR connector uses different attributes for SSL
>   keys and certificates."

Netbeans must put the APR libs onto the classpath, which aren't there when running manually.

Comment: Good spot! I've faced a similar issue with IntelliJ IDEA.